# My code works with Eclipse but cannot compile with javac - JDK7

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

My code compiles and works well in Eclipse. I have exported .jar also. But when I compile it on my build server with ant and javac, it gives an error message and cannot compile.

This happens after I changed the `JList` to `JList<Object>`. I changed it because someone said the generic raw type is not safe.

Should I use the raw type again? or is there another idea?

PS. Version of javac in server is 1.7.0_72 and My eclipse version is 4.4.1

My code:

```
public class CheckListManager  extends MouseAdapter implements ListSelectionListener, ActionListener{ 
    private ListSelectionModel selectionModel = new DefaultListSelectionModel(); 
    private JList<Object> list = new JList<Object>();
    int hotspot = new JCheckBox().getPreferredSize().width; 

    public CheckListManager(JList<Object> list) {
        this.list = list; 
        list.setCellRenderer(new CheckListCellRenderer(list.getCellRenderer(), selectionModel)); 
        list.registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED); 
        list.addMouseListener(this); 
        selectionModel.addListSelectionListener(this); 
    }

    (... so on)

    private class CheckListCellRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer<Object> {
        public CheckListCellRenderer(ListCellRenderer<Object> renderer, ListSelectionModel selectionModel) {

        (...)

        }
    }
}
```

error code:

```
C:\BuildSite_United\trunk\java\XE Core\src\com\psia\core\view\util\CheckListManager.java:29: error: constructor CheckListCellRenderer in class CheckListManager.CheckListCellRenderer cannot be applied to given types;
        list.setCellRenderer(new CheckListCellRenderer(list.getCellRenderer(), selectionModel));
                             ^
  required: ListCellRenderer<Object>,ListSelectionModel
  found: ListCellRenderer<CAP#1>,ListSelectionModel
  reason: actual argument ListCellRenderer<CAP#1> cannot be converted to ListCellRenderer<Object> by method invocation conversion
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object super: Object from capture of ? super Object
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using in eclipse?

Comment: if your application is based on SWT, JFACE, or other. there is no related library in JDK.

Comment: Elliott Frisch // javac is 1.7.0_72 and eclipse is 4.4.1

Comment: CHmoonKa // It works well with raw type code. about 1 weeks ago.

Comment: what version of java is running on your build server? Is it less than 1.5? You can check the version by using command "java -version". Confirm the path used by your script is still the same JDK 7. As there could be multiple versions on your server.

Comment: My script use "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72\bin\javac" and javac version is 1.7.0_72